# Inert cyanide groups in polyacrylonitrile(PAN)

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers

Cyanide group undergoes hydrolysis and gets converted to Carboxylic acid. However, the cyanide groups in polyacrylonitrile(PAN) are inert. Why?

Comment: But PAN does hydrolyse to an extent. There are plenty of articles on it...

Comment: so PAN is not a good polymer?